# About Resistor packages, inductor packages and capacitor packages

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor

I want to know what is meant by Resistor, capacitor, and inductor packages. what are differnt catagories in them.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: "Package" is literally the outer casing of the component; are you asking what designations like "0402" mean?

Comment: I know this is probably surprising to people, but I have had students ask me this before, they have not know what I mean by package or why they care.

Answer (score 12):

There are two main categories of component (passive or active, but we are focusing on passive here); through hole and surface mount. Wikipedia has extensive information on this subject (e.g. [resistor page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor), [capacitor page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor), etc), and [JEDEC](http://www.jedec.org/) is a standards organisation that deals with chip/passive packages.

In each category, there are many many sizes and shape of package and lead position. For example in the through hole category you have axial (leads on axis) and radial (leads both at on side) leaded components.

Axial resistor packages (values colour coded):

[image: Axial resistors]

Radial resistor package (values printed):

[image: Radial resistor]

There are also arrays such as this SIL (Single In Line) package:

[image: SIL]

The above applies similarly for capacitors and inductors.

**Surface Mount**

[Surface mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology) means that no holes are necessary in the PCB to mount the component, rather a copper pad on the surface. Common packages for passives are named accrding to the length/width of the package, such as 0402, 0603, 0805, and so on, with e.g. 0402 meaning the package is 20 mils wide and 40 mils long. There are also metric equivalents (e.g. 0402 = 1005 = 1mm x 0.5mm metric)

[image: SMD Package sizes]

Example packages (with two through hole shown at right for comparison):

[image: Package examples]

The values for SMD resistors are usually given with 3 digits, the first two being the first two significant digits of the values and the third being a multiplier in power of ten. For example:

100 = 10 * 10^0 = 10 * 1 = 10Ω (not 100Ω!)
222 = 22 * 10^2 = 22 * 100 = 2.2kΩ

SMT Capacitors are often not marked at all (see brownish parts in above picture), and inductors vary similarly.

**Why are there so many different sizes?**

Depending on the component, there are a few different reasons:

- Power dissipation - this is important for resistors, since the bigger they are the more power they can handle. So you can have many resistors of the same value, but with different power ratings. 1/4W is a typical value for an axial leaded resistor.
  Ideal inductors and capacitors don't dissipate energy, they only store it. In the real world though they do, for capacitors (ESR - Equivalent Series Resistance - ideally low, especially for capacitors used for power supply smoothing) and inductor/transformers (resistance of windings, core losses) this can become an issue.
- Voltage rating - for a capacitor this is particularly important. Since a higher capacitance is achieved with a smaller distance between plates, the dielectric (insulator between plates, material depends on capacitor type) can be very thin indeed. So generally for the same dielectric and size, the higher the capacitance, the lower the voltage rating. This is because the thinner the dielectric, the lower the voltage needed to break it down and create a short between the plates. Some capacitors designed for use between mains wiring have a "self-healing" dielectric (known as X and Y capacitors)
  For an inductor, the maximum voltage may be to do with winding insulation breakdown, or simply the winding resistance. Generally a maximum current is specified for the latter case.
  For a resistor, this would be the point where breakdown of the material itself or arcing across the terminals could occur. If the resistors terminals are closer together, the less the peak voltage rating will be. Often the resistance value itself and package power rating will limit the voltage on a long time scale, but there is still a peak pulse voltage rating, and specialised resistors designed to handle large pulses are available.
- Current Rating - for cored inductors, there is also a [saturation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_%28magnetic%29) current rating, where the core cannot magnetise any further (i.e. it is saturated) so the inductance/impedance becomes non-linear. The ESR of a capacitor will cause self heating at large charge/discharge currents, so a peak pulse current and time scale maybe specified (e.g. dV/dt rating)

Any good component will have a decent datasheet with all the ratings clearly specified, so even for "simple" passive components, you need to make sure the part is suitable for the job. Information not discussed above, like capacitance change over applied voltage (many are unaware of this effect), temperature, etc should be mentioned.

The above note are very simplified, to get an idea of how complex the various non-ideal effects are, see this application note from Epcos on [power capacitors](http://www.epcos.com/web/generator/Web/Sections/ProductCatalog/Capacitors/PDF/PDF__GeneralTechnicalInformation,property=Data__en.pdf;/PDF_GeneralTechnicalInformation.pdf)

Comment: Maybe worth discussing power rating reason for picking package also, you already have a +1 from me, but just a suggestion.

Comment: @Kortuk - I added a bit more on size and ratings. Was a bit rushed so let me know if you spot any errors.